# Polygon made from raster extent does not display exactly same as raster in Google Earth Pro?

Tags: r, google-earth-pro

Polygon made from a raster extent does not display exactly the same as the raster in google earth pro.

Does anyone else have this problem?

```
 new_crs<-crs(dem_10)#get latlon
 r2<-projectRaster(r1, crs=new_crs)# project to latlon
 p <- as((extent(r2)), 'SpatialPolygons')# get extent polygon
 KML(r2, file="example_data.kml")# write raster to kml
 KML(p, file="example_data_extent.kml")#write polyogn to kml
```

[image: raster extent polygon not matching raster extent]

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your original raster, `r1`, wasn't in lat-long (you don't tell us anything about it, so its a guess). When you project this into lat-long for `r2`, your original raster gets rotated slightly, and padded out with missing values (`NA`).

This makes the extent in lat-long not be the same as the extent in the original CRS - which is what you are seeing. The red box in the image is aligned to the lat-long axes, and you can see it touching the non-NA pixels at four points.